# Is the heap-allocated object of a class alive after its scope but before calling its destructor in C++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

EDITED: Let's say we don't call explicitely the destructor of a heap-based object (delete A). If the pointer that points to "A" goes out-of-scope, is there a way the dynamic object remain accessible? for e.g., in the following code, can "a" be still alive after if-closing }?

```
class A{
  void itsmethod();

 };


int main()
{
  if (true){
   A* a = new A;
  }
   //...here how can I use dynamically allocated object?
   a->itsmethod();
}
```

EDIT: As it was responded, the simplest immediate way is defining the pointer outside of if statement, but I am just wondering if there is any other option to prolong lifetime of dynamic object? Accordingly what else "A" class should provide? For instance passing by reference? Or equipping the class with move constructor... These suggestions may be irrelevant, I would like to hear your feedback.

Comment: Not `a`, but the object it's pointing to will still be "alive" in memory.

Comment: The object can't be alive because the code won't compile.

Comment: `a` is scoped to `if block` so it is inaccessible from outside.

Comment: @juanchopanza Are you saying that because this isn’t a *complete* example? It has all the information you actually *need*, you *know* how to fill in the `...`, and since this is a theory question you don’t need to run the code yourself.

Comment: @DanielH I disagree. It is currently broken in a crucial way that makes the question moot.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nobody, neither the OP nor anybody else, cares about the code actually posted in the question. It is an example to illustrate what the questions is asking. It succeeds at illustrating what the question was asking, unless you mean to say you honestly don’t understand what is being asked about object lifetimes.

Comment: @DanielH I care. If you start pretending scope isn't a thing in C++, then you have a handle to the pointer that you can deal with after main exits, so no memory leak.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought your complaint was about the `...` in the definition of `class A`. For the use of the pointer, that obviously isn’t valid code, as the OP knows *because they ask this question* instead of assuming it works. Adding the word “how” and two slashes is a minor change which doesn’t help readability very much.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if the object "a" is still alive after if-closing }?

The object `a`, which is a pointer, is not alive after the closing `}` of the `if` statement. The object to which `a` points to is in memory but it is not accessible with the posted code.

To be able to access the object to which `a` points to, declare `a` before the `if` statement.

```
int main()
{
   A* a = nullptr;

   if (true)
   {
      a = new A;
   }

   if ( a != nullptr )
   {
      a->itsmethod();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No and Yes: yes because dynamic memory is not freed up automatically. No because the code doesn't compile because `a` is scoped to if block and you are trying to use it from outside.

```
class A{
    public:
        int x;
};

int main(){

    A* ptrA = NULL;

    if(true){
        // Everything declared here is accessible only here whatever being dynamic or static.
        ptrA = new A;
        ptrA->x = 10;

        int x;
    }

    if(ptrA){
        std::cout << ptrA->x << std::endl; // 10
        delete ptrA;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

You must free up memory always when you're done with it otherwise it is a memory leak.

- Above `x` is declared inside the `if` block on the stack so when end of if block is reached `x` will be destructed.

Answer (score 2):

The object created by the `new` expression   (i.e. by `new A`) will continue to exist.

The pointer `a` itself, since it has passed out of scope, will cease to exist as far as your program is concerned.

The net effect is that the dynamically allocated object is "leaked".   It continues to exist after the block but there is no pointer or reference to it.

If you do something like

```
int main()
{
   A *b;
   if (true)
   {
      A* a = new A;
      b = a;
   }

   a->itsmethod();    //  diagnosible error
   b->itsmethod();    //    will work correctly
   delete b;          //   destroy dynamically allocated object
   b->itsmethod();    //   undefined behaviour
}
```

then `a->itsmethod()` will give a compiler diagnostic (since `a` no longer exists) but the first `b->itsmethod()` will use the object created by the `new` expression.     The second `b->itsmethod()` will compile, but yield undefined behaviour, since it accesses an object that no longer exists (due to the preceding `delete b`).

This happens because the pointer `b` continues to exist and, within the enclosed block, is assigned the value from `a`.  So it then contains the result of the new expression.

Answer (score 1):

No. The object 'a' will not be accessible anymore since its scope belongs to the if statement. However, there still is a memory address containing that object. This is why its good to do 'garbage collection' in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    const char *s;
    std::ostream & operator ()( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        return os << s;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A *a1;

    if ( true )
    {
        A *a2 = new A { "Hello, Sepideha" };

        a1 = a2;
    }

    ( *a1 )() << std::endl;

    delete a1;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello, Sepideha
```

Here the object `a1` that has the type `A *` has the outer-most block scope of the function main.

The object `a2` has the block scope of the if statement. It is alive only within this block.
At the same time there is dynamically created unnamed object of the type `A` pointer to which is assigned to `a2` and then to `a1`. This unnamed object will be alive until the operator delete for a pointer that points to the object will be called. That is its live-time does not depend on the block scope of the if statement.

Because the pointer `a1` points to this unnamed object then the pointer can be used outside the if statement to access the unnamed object in the dynamic memory.

After the statement with the delete operator this unnamed object stops to exist. But the object `a1` is still alive.